# Code not filtering the ASCII characters

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

Users might enter some invalid characters for example those arrow keys below that are ASCII code of 26

> Pawn Paws → → H

So I have a code to filter that range like this:

```
m_dir = New [String](m_dir.Where(Function(c) (Asc(c) >= 32) AndAlso (Asc(c) <= 175)).ToArray())
```

But looks like it is NOT working. Because still I am getting the same string back with arrows in it.

Comment: Also depends on the encoding of your string, if it's Unicode.

Comment: @the_lotus What happens if it is Unicode? What should change?

Comment: Strings have been Unicode since VB4. Use AscW to stick with Unicode; Asc converts to an encoding (code page) that varies over machines, users, and time.

Comment: @TomBlodget  That fixed it. Post it as answer if you want.